# Laravel and mysql in docker: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, containers

I have two docker containers running in the same network:

- [bitnami/laravel:9.1.10](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/laravel)
- [mysql:8.0.29](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

My database setup in `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=[ip from container]
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=todos
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=[password]
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` in my laravel container it creates tables in `todos` database without problems.

The problem exists when in my app, a form tries to add a new task in "todos" table:

My code:

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|min:3'
        ]);

        $todo= new Todo;
        $todo->title = $request->title;
        $todo->save();

        return redirect()->route('todos')->with('success', 'Todo added!');
    }
```

And the error:

**Illuminate\Database\ QueryException**

**SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb failed: Name or service not known**

```sql
insert into `todos` (`title`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (example, 2022-06-28 19:29:28, 2022-06-28 19:29:28)
```

I don't know if it is a connection problem because the migration works correctly.

In `config/database.php` I have:

```php
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

And for mysql in `connections`:

```php
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

I don't see where is the `mariadb connection`

Comment: the .env is one thing, the other is the config/database.php, how is set the data over there ?

Comment: It's trying to connect to a database with the hostname of mariadb instead of the IP. As Albert said, double-check the configuration in `config/database.php` for the default and the connections

Comment: In `database.php` I don't change anything, because the default connection is set to `mysql`. Am I right?